# Hdfs file or folder created or modified date using python

Tags: python-2.7, hdfs

To find number of days a file or folder is created for in hdfs, I used following python code.

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime

def get_days(directory, file)

    current_datetime = datetime.now()
    command = "hadoop fs -ls " + directory + file + " | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f6-7 | grep '^[0-9]' "
    status, output = shell_command(command)
        if status == 0:
            file_date = datetime.strptime(output, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
            date_period = current_datetime - file_date
    return date_period.days
```

It threw following error

```
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime (data_string, format)) 
ValueError: time data 'log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation).\nlog4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.\nlog4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.\n2018-04-11 14:08' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'
```

The only reason I can think of is that the output is a variable of inferred type Unicode. Is there any other way to find the modified date or age of a Hdfs file in python? please advise. Any changes to the above code are also welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try webhdfs APIs, https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html

Answer (score 1):

Below code worked for me:

```
import datetime
import commands
from datetime import datetime

def get_days(directory, file):    
    current_datetime = datetime.now()
    command = "hadoop fs -ls " + directory + file + " | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f6-7 | grep '^[0-9]' "
    (status, output) = commands.getstatusoutput(command)
        if status == 0:
            file_date = datetime.strptime(output, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
            date_period = current_datetime - file_date
    return date_period.days
```

Comment: You can also read the fs-image of cluster to get the metadata. In that you could find all the details of a block or file and their modification date. fs image are in binary format, so we can access it using hdfs oiv command (hdfs oiv –i /fsimage/fsimage_00000000xyz --> offline image viewer)

Comment: You can also use the command "hdfs dfs -stat <path_file>" to get the modified date and some other metadata as well

Comment: Thanks for your answer Rahul. I will try fs-image and -stat. The problem I faced with above code was it worked fine during unit testing but when I put it in a workflow that runs daily, it started giving above mentioned error after few days. I couldn't find any reason, so I am trying for a method to avoid passing console output to 'strptime'.

Comment: Hi Rahul, Hadoop fs -stat is giving date and time as console output but again I have the same doubt of strptime function throwing error after deployment when I use that.

Comment: Could you print the "output " and see if you are getting the expected output i.e the correct format. From the error , we could identify that the format is not as expected. For me its working fine. Also I have used the "commands" package instead of your "shell_command" method